# Генерация диаграмм классов в Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio

Возникла необходимость генерации диаграммы классов для проекта. В студии есть отдельный тип файлов - Class Diagram. Вроде бы то, что надо, но нужно иметь возможность видеть связи между классами не только по наследованию, но и по использованию. Например, если в классе A я обращаюсь к методам статического класса B, хочелось бы на диаграмме видеть связь между A и B. Позволяет ли VS подобное, и, если нет, есть ли другие варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, всё это применимо только в Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

То, что Вы хотите, называется Dependency Graph.

```
Architecture -> Generate Dependency Graph -> For Solution
```

Студия построит солюшн и отобразит диаграмму на котором будут показаны взаимосвязи между классами, причём не только Вашими, но и mscorlib ей не трудно разложить по полочкам.

Например, [вот](http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/8935/sampledg.png) скриншот моей студии с классом-примером и построенной диаграммой.

Comment: огромное спасибо! то, что нужно.